# Is there a way to detect changes within the same route?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

With Iron Router, I have the following route set up:

```
Router.route('/:cat', {
    name: "goods",
    waitOn: function() {
        Session.setDefault('limit', 20)
        var limit = Session.get('limit') || 20
        Meteor.subscribe('goods', this.params.cat, limit)
    }
})
```

The idea is that the user can press a bunch of buttons to change the `cat`(egory), filtering out some data but remaining on the same route. Classic stuff.

Right now it just sets a default `limit` of 20 and as the user scrolls down, it is increased. If he clicks a button to change category, it doesn't make sense to instantly load 100 new items, but set the `limit` back to 20 again.

Problem is, I can't really think of a good way to do that. Removing the `setDefault` to use a `Session.set` won't work. All I can think of right now is logging the `cat` in a `Session` and use that to check if the category has been changed, but I was hoping there is a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure that doing this in your `waitOn` makes sense. Have you tried using [template subscriptions](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/)? The example from that post is particularly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the template to manage the state (instead of sessions and the route.

For example, using a reactivate variable (reactive-var package), and passing the category through the route to the template. This way - categories can be linked to (and the limits expanded/limited as needed).

Start by instantiating the template

```
Template.limitedDatasource.created = function() {
  this.data.limitVar = new ReactiveVar(20);
  this.data.dsSub = Meteor.subscribe('goods', this.data.category, this.data.limitVar.get())
}
```

Add some template level helpers to manage the subscription readyness and the data

```
Template.limitedDatasource.helpers({
    dataSourceReady: function() {
        return this.dsSub.ready();
    },
    dataSource: function() {
        return CollectioName.find({cat: this.category}, {limit: this.limitVar.get()});
    }
});
```

Add some event handlers to load in more things (maybe change the limit?)

```
Template.limitedDatasource.events({
    'click .showMore': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newLimit = template.data.limitVar.get() + 20;
        template.data.limitVar.set(newLimit);
    },

});
```